# How can I pass a dynamic attribute to Nifi EvaluateJsonPath?

Tags: apache-nifi, datastax-astra

Currently, I'm building a 3rd party automated data collection process, through NiFi that runs automatically syncing data to datastax Astra. Here is a sample api return I got from a third party.

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "project_name": "ALS Data",
    "descriptions": "This is my first project",
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "345",
            "full_name": "John",
            "role": "Front-End"
        },
        {
            "id": "456",
            "full_name": "Iko Juno",
            "role": "Backend"
        }
    ]
}
```

- I want to filter through the list of each member and call the api of datastax Astra to save the data there. Enpoint API in datastax Astra
  `{BaseURL}/api/rest/v1/keyspaces/{keyspaces_name}/tables/{table_name}/rows.`
- In NiFi, I tried using `EvaluJsonPath` to get each value of the Members array (in the api return I mentioned above). However, I find using `EvaluateJsonPath` doesn't seem to work as I only get exactly 1 object that I pass in. Example: `$.members[0].id`

[image: the process i built in nifi]

How can i pass a dynamic attribute to `EvaluateJsonPath` so that I can get all the data in the returned array and import them into datastax Astra through Astra's built-in api. Or any other way to handle this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try $.members[*].id

Comment: Hi @edjm thank for your comment.
But I have used the same as you, but the returned result is in the form id = [345,456] which does not match the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you want to extract the `members` array from the API response and then do further processing.

So to replicate your case I made use of `GenerateFlowFile` which generates me a flowfile, I copied the API response you shared above and added it to the properties tab.

Next I make use of the `SplitJson` processor, this takes care of splitting the single flowfile into multiple files based on the split property provided. In this case as I wanted to get all the values from the `members` array, I used `$.members`

[image: Sample Flow]

Now running the process once you can see the below output at each stage

*Generate FlowFile*

[image: Generate Flowfile]

*SplitJson*

[image: SplitJson]

[image: SplitJson flowfile]

You would have two flowfiles at the end of the `SplitJson` as the API response had two values in the members array. After this you can do further processing as needed.

Comment: @KienNguyen you are welcome, if the above suggestion work. You can mark the question as answered as it would help other people who have the same issue

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your answer @DataWrangler.
My problem was solved according to your suggestion. Thank you very much